# Which are the sweetest alcoholic drinks?

Tags: taste, recommendations

I am attending a company party that will be serving these alcoholic drinks:

1. Belvedere Vodka
2. Bulleit Bourbon
3. Don Julio Silver Tequila
4. La Marcca Prosecco
5. L. Martini Cab Sauvignon
6. Dry Creek Sauvignon Blanc
7. Stella Artois
8. Lagunitas IPA
9. Coronado Mermaids Red
10. Blue Moon
11. Bud Light

I am an alcohol novice who mostly likes to drink the sweeter alcoholic drinks and not the very bitter ones. Which of these drinks are the sweetest?

Comment: Try the Prosecco. Not all proseccos are sweet, but probably they are more to your liking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the beverages that you have listed, the following are likely to be considered the sweetest:

> La Marcca Prosecco
>
> L. Martini Cab Sauvignon
>
> Dry Creek Sauvignon Blanc

In general, wines will be sweeter than liquors and beers simply due to the fact that they are made from grapes.

However, this is made under the assumption that any of the liquors you listed will be served straight or neat... If instead the liquors will be served in cocktails, you might actually prefer one of those.

Commonly, a novice drinkers tend to enjoy clear liquor over dark. And, vodka is one liquor in which many very sweet juices, like pineapple, are mixed to make rather delicious cocktails that can even be described as "light" and/or "refreshing." A [lemon drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_drop) is sometimes made with simple syrup (basically sugar water) and served with sugar around the rim, much in the same way a margarita (another sweet cocktail made usually made with tequila) is served with salt around the rim.

You may want to research any [list of sweet cocktails](https://www.supercall.com/entertaining/best-sweet-cocktails) in advance, determine which sounds the tastiest for your palate among the liquors to be served, and ask for that particular one when you are at the party.

Answer (score 1):

**Which are the sweetest alcoholic drinks?**

Each person will perceive tastes a little differently and nothing is full proof in this domain.

Since you are a novice, it may be good to avoid the liquor unless you are using them in some cocktails. In this case, I would go with vodka.

For the list you site, I would give thought to **Coronado Mermaid’s Red Ale**.

> A well balanced, medium-to full bodied beer, red in color and very flavorful. The red color and slight caramel-roasted flavor comes from generous amounts of caramel malts and a touch of chocolate malts. Well hopped to balance the malty sweetness, and dry-hopped with cascade for a full hop flavor and aroma. - [Coronado Mermaid's Red Ale](https://winefolly.com/tutorial/wine-sweetness-chart/)

[Stella Artois](http://www.fearlesscritic.com/beer/69/stella-artois) would probably not to your liking. But again, you may enjoy it.

I find some light beer quite sweet, but that is me.

In order to help you discern what wines are possibly sweeter, I am posting a couple of wine sweetness charts for the benefit of all.

> Red wines have tannin which makes wines taste less sweet than they actually are.
>
> White wines have higher acidity which can make wines taste less sweet. - [Wine Sweetness Chart](https://winefolly.com/tutorial/wine-sweetness-chart/)

[image]